# Convexity of polylogaritms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I want to prove the following proposition:

The function $w\to (-Li_{5/2}(-e^w))^{2/5}$ is convex on $\mathbb R$.

And, as I think, the same is true for the function $w\to (-Li_{p}(-e^w))^{1/p}$ for $p\ge 1$ ([wiki on polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)). I didn't find any direct results on this subject.

For bounded $w$ it's possible to build a plot in, say, Mathematica, and see that the proposition is true there. For $w\to\infty$ I can find the asymptotical behaviour: $c_1w+c_2/w +\mathcal O(w^{-2})$, $c_i>0$.

Hence, two questions. Is this development sufficient to guarantee convexity? And what to do on the region where the asymptotics isn't true yet? Of course, I can build a plot on a sufficiently large compact, but to correctly choose the latter seems to be quite a complex task, too.

Computing the second derivative doesn't yield anything useful, or, at least, I can't prove that the sign is constant.

$\frac{\left(-Li_p(-e^w)\right)^{1/p-2}\left(p Li_{p-2}(-e^w)Li_p(-e^w)-(p-1)(-Li_{p-1}(-e^w))^2\right)}{p^2}$

I'd be glad to hear all suggestions on the possible reasoning for my proposition.

Comment: Polylogarithm $Li_p(z)$ is real-valued for $p>0$, $z\in (-\infty,1)$. Since $w\in \mathbb R$, in our case $Li_p(-e^w)$ is always real-valued.

Comment: Did you manage to find a clean proof of this claim?

Comment: @Suvrit : in fact, I did find the proof for $p\ge 2$. It appears that it's a direct consequence of the representation $-Li_{p}(-e^w) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{p-1}dt}{e^{t+w}+1}$ and MateuszWasilewski's comment to [this question(link)](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134511/conditions-on-a-measure-to-satisfy-certain-relation-on-moments) on MO. If you need further details, I'll post it as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: I was wondering about the $p \ge 1$ case in general. Also, isn't that $e^{t-w}+1$ in the denominator, and not $e^{t+w}+1$?

Comment: @Suvrit Of course, you're right, it should be $e^{t-w}+1$. We know that $-Li_1(-e^w)=\ln(1+e^w)$ is convex. For the case $p\in (1,2)$ I can't say much, because the representation via that integral no longer works for the second derivative, it involves another representation, which uses hyperbolic and standard sinuses (and thus quite hard to estimate). I think there might be a way to prove it numerically, i.e. build estimations on the behaviour outside a well-chosen compact and build a plot inside that compact.

Comment: @Suvrit But the case $p\ge 2$ was largely sufficient for my needs at the moment, so I didn't really study the case $p<2$. One day I plan to return to that problem=)

Comment: Also one final point: $-Li_p(-e^w)$ is *not* log-convex in $p$ (because of division by $\Gamma(p)$). But really nice question you posed!